# Calling SOAP with Golang

Tags: go, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am new to golang and trying make a soap call with [gowsdl](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZhrCzstDXAhXIhRoKHSjUDosQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fhooklift%2Fgowsdl&usg=AOvVaw1Yo3mgaI9pVrSym9gqxClb) .

I have generated the wsdl code and installed it as a package. I am however struggling to understand the syntax for call the method from it.

When I examine the package, this is what I want in the soap body:

```
type AccountUser struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI AccountUser"`

    *APIObject

    AccountUserID             int32         `xml:"AccountUserID,omitempty"`
    UserID                    string        `xml:"UserID,omitempty"`
    Password                  string        `xml:"Password,omitempty"`
    Name                      string        `xml:"Name,omitempty"`
    Email                     string        `xml:"Email,omitempty"`
    MustChangePassword        bool          `xml:"MustChangePassword,omitempty"`
    ActiveFlag                bool          `xml:"ActiveFlag,omitempty"`
    ChallengePhrase           string        `xml:"ChallengePhrase,omitempty"`
    ChallengeAnswer           string        `xml:"ChallengeAnswer,omitempty"`
    UserPermissions           []*UserAccess `xml:"UserPermissions,omitempty"`
    Delete                    int32         `xml:"Delete,omitempty"`
    LastSuccessfulLogin       time.Time     `xml:"LastSuccessfulLogin,omitempty"`
    IsAPIUser                 bool          `xml:"IsAPIUser,omitempty"`
    NotificationEmailAddress  string        `xml:"NotificationEmailAddress,omitempty"`
    IsLocked                  bool          `xml:"IsLocked,omitempty"`
    Unlock                    bool          `xml:"Unlock,omitempty"`
    BusinessUnit              int32         `xml:"BusinessUnit,omitempty"`
    DefaultBusinessUnit       int32         `xml:"DefaultBusinessUnit,omitempty"`
    DefaultApplication        string        `xml:"DefaultApplication,omitempty"`
    Locale                    *Locale       `xml:"Locale,omitempty"`
    TimeZone                  *TimeZone     `xml:"TimeZone,omitempty"`
    DefaultBusinessUnitObject *BusinessUnit `xml:"DefaultBusinessUnitObject,omitempty"`

    AssociatedBusinessUnits struct {
        BusinessUnit []*BusinessUnit `xml:"BusinessUnit,omitempty"`
    } `xml:"AssociatedBusinessUnits,omitempty"`

    Roles struct {
        Role []*Role `xml:"Role,omitempty"`
    } `xml:"Roles,omitempty"`

    LanguageLocale *Locale `xml:"LanguageLocale,omitempty"`

    SsoIdentities struct {
        SsoIdentity []*SsoIdentity `xml:"SsoIdentity,omitempty"`
    } `xml:"SsoIdentities,omitempty"`
}
```

And the method to call the SOAP is :

```
func (s *SOAPClient) Call(soapAction string, request, response interface{}) error {
    envelope := SOAPEnvelope{
    //Header:        SoapHeader{},
    }

    envelope.Body.Content = request
    buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)

    encoder := xml.NewEncoder(buffer)
    //encoder.Indent("  ", "    ")

    if err := encoder.Encode(envelope); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := encoder.Flush(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Println(buffer.String())

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", s.url, buffer)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if s.auth != nil {
        req.SetBasicAuth(s.auth.Login, s.auth.Password)
    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"")
    if soapAction != "" {
        req.Header.Add("SOAPAction", soapAction)
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "gowsdl/0.1")
    req.Close = true

    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: s.tls,
        },
        Dial: dialTimeout,
    }

    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    rawbody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(rawbody) == 0 {
        log.Println("empty response")
        return nil
    }

    log.Println(string(rawbody))
    respEnvelope := new(SOAPEnvelope)
    respEnvelope.Body = SOAPBody{Content: response}
    err = xml.Unmarshal(rawbody, respEnvelope)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fault := respEnvelope.Body.Fault
    if fault != nil {
        return fault
    }

    return nil
}
```

I have imported the package into my go file , and would love pointers on how to call this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use the generated code you obviously will have to first initialize the soap client with one of the generated "constructor" functions `NewSOAPClient` or `NewSOAPClientWithTLSConfig`.

After that you'll need to prepare **two** values that you can use as the request and response arguments to the `Call` method, they represent the body content of the soap request/response payloads.

The types of those two values will depend on what kind of call you want to make, for example the hypothetical calls create_account, update_account, and delete_account would usually require different types. Basically, the type of the `request` value should be *marshalable* into an xml that matches the xml expected by the soap service for the specified action, and the type of the `response` should be *unmarshalable* from an xml that matches the soap service's documented response for the specified action.

---

Consider this contrived example:

There is a SOAP service that allows you to create users. For you to be able to create a user with the service it requires you to send an email and a password, and if everyting's ok it will return an id. In such a case your two request/response types would look like this:

```
type CreateUserRequest struct {
    Email    string `xml:"Email,omitempty"`
    Password string `xml:"Password,omitempty"`
}

type CreateUserResponse struct {
    ID string `xml:"ID"`
}
```

Then the client code would look like this:

```
client := NewSOAPClient("https://soap.example.com/call", true, nil)

req := &CreateUserRequest{
    Email:    "jdoe@example.com",
    Password: "1234567890",
}
res := &CreateUserResponse{}
if err := client.Call("create_user", req, res); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// if everything went well res.ID should have its
// value set with the one returned by the service.
fmt.Println(res.ID)
```